# bash shell "Would you like to continue [Y / n]"

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to write a script that automates the execution of
`sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg x264 libvpx libav-tools-dev libx264-dev`.
This command displays at the middle of the execution: `Would you like to continue [Y / n]?`
I want my script to execute without having to ask me to type "Y" to continue.

I added just after this command: `echo -e "Y\r"`, but it is not considered?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg x264 libav-tools libvpx-dev libx264-dev

echo -e "Y\r"
```

Answer (score 8):

Specify `-y` to your `apt-get` command:

`sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg x264 libav-tools libvpx-dev libx264-dev`

From `apt-get --help`

```
-y  Assume Yes to all queries and do not prompt
```

Answer (score 8):

The most general way of automatically answering these questions is to use [the `yes` utility](http://man.cx/yes) and pipe it into whatever other program is asking them. e.g.

```
yes | sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg x264 libav-tools libvpx-dev libx264-dev
```

However, as @Rohan says, in this case `apt-get` has equivalent functionality built in, so use that instead.

(NB. you can customise the string `yes` outputs. E.g. one could answer "n" to every question like:

```
yes n | sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg x264 libav-tools libvpx-dev libx264-dev
```

)